# Document.cookie not deleting

Tags: javascript, cookies, document

My code is as simple as the line

```
document.cookie = "loggedIn=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
```

I check the cookies before it and loggedIn=true, then I check after and it still exists... 
I am using Chrome 34.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it!

The issue was I did not include the path in the string, although I am not sure why the path is needed, I thought it would use the default...

```
document.cookie = "loggedIn=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
```

The above works!